# -bash: gulp: command not found in Mac

Tags: macos, bash, npm, gulp

I try install gulp in mac like this :

```
Is-iMac:~ itop$ npm root
/Users/itop/node_modules
Is-iMac:~ itop$ npm config set prefix /usr/local
Is-iMac:~ itop$ npm root -g
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
Is-iMac:~ itop$ sudo npm install -g gulp
```

After Install I see this error In terminal:

```
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/gulp
npm ERR! code EEXIST

npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/gulp: ../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/gulp
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/it/npm-debug.log
```

Now when i type `gulp` for start/run in terminal i see this error:

```
-bash: gulp: command not found
```

**EDIT:**
I try with this comment By [archie-voyageur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5652719/archie-voyageur):

```
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

And See this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/gulp -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--global" "gulp-cli"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/share/man/man1/gulp.1
npm ERR! code EEXIST

npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/share/man/man1/gulp.1: ../../../lib/node_modules/gulp/gulp.1 symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/share/man/man1/gulp.1
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/itop/npm-debug.log
```

How do fix this?

Comment: @ArchieVoyageur: thanks i try This please see My Edit.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what's unclear about `File exists,  Move it away, and try again.` ....

Answer (score 83):

Just came across this issue myself and managed to solve it with:

```
$ npm uninstall --global gulp gulp-cli
$ rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/gulp.1
$ npm install --global gulp-cli
```

Comment: Worked for me Nov 2017 - OSX Sierra.

Answer (score 8):

**go to**

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ls -las
```

> if gulp is present delete that directory. (sudo rm -rf gulp) reinstall
>   gulp-cli

===================================================================

***if it is not working uninstall node, npm completely and try again***

> follow this link for step by step guide

[node and npm uninstall step by step](https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have gulp installed in your system, or at least you have some files related to gulp. Just do `npm uninstall --global gulp gulp-cli` and then try to install it again with `npm install --global gulp-cli`. If this doesn't work, I don't know what is happening on your system.

Comment: The only thing coming to my head that you could do is unistall Node from your system and install it from scratch again. But I don't have much hope about that becuase I don't know what is cuasing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After pulling my hair out trying all of these, I ended up being able to install stupid gulp by doing

```
npm uninstall --global gulp gulp-cli

yarn global add gulp
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it worked only when I installed `gulp` using `npm` instead of `yarn`. Very weird..