# Why is gulp: command not found after installing it globally - Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, git-bash

I'm having a problem installing gulp globally with **npm 5.3.0** and **node v8.5.0.**

First I did install gulp

```
$ npm install gulp-cli --global
```

then

```
$ gulp
```

results to

```
bash: gulp: command not found
```

I already tried answers from these questions:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24042936/8680741
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40197889/8680741
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25126461/8680741
4. npm install and npm update

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is what I did https://servimg.com/view/19521718/6 
     https://servimg.com/view/19521718/5

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask], the [Tour] and how to create an [mcve]. Particularly, don't link images of code, but if you must, at least inline them as I have done in the edit. It makes is easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @msanford I did what you suggested. I hope it's okay now. Please help me with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: What version of nodejs and npm are you running: `npm -v && node -v`?

Comment: npm -v 5.3.0  && node -v v8.5.0

Comment: The problem is that your npm root (which I can't copy because it's an image ;) is not in your `PATH`. Add it in `~/.profile` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: Is `\Program Files\Git\usr\local\lib\` in your path ?

Comment: This is my $ npm root
C:\Users\Jash\node_modules

Comment: I'm really sorry I'm not sure what PATH you are talking about. Please explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Git Bash is listing global modules directory in your (`~/.bash_profile`, which is same as `C:\Users\Jash\.bash_profile`). I think, you will need to add a line in the very beginning of that file:

```
export PATH="/c/Program Files/nodejs/":$PATH
```